# Can you use C++ concepts in the same way as polymorphic interfaces?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++-concepts

I have just stumbled over C++20's "concepts", something that I've wanted in the language for years... well kind of.

Consider the code below:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
concept IFoo = requires(T t) {
    { t.foo() } -> std::convertible_to<int>;
};

class FooImpl
{
    public:
        int foo() const { return 3; }
};

template <IFoo Foo>
void doSomething(const Foo& foo) {
    std::cout << foo.foo() << "\n";
    std::cout << foo.bar() << "\n"; // I want this to be an error!
}

int main() {
    FooImpl foo;
    doSomething(foo); // No error if this is commented out
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to use the concept `IFoo` as you would use a normal polymorphic interface (= pure virtual class). The problem that I have is that the call `foo.bar()` does not produce a compile error, merely a substitution error. This means that the concept `IFoo` could lie to you, for example when coding like this:

1. Write `doSomething` where you only call `foo.foo()` and create the concept for documentation
2. Two weeks later: Extend `doSomething` to also call `foo.bar()` and forget to update the concept.
3. Another two weeks later: Write a test for `doSomething` and be dumbfounded when you get a template error even though you completely satisfy the concept in your mock implementation of `IFoo`.

Right now, I don't see the advantage of using concepts over simple doc comments:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class FooImpl
{
    public:
        int foo() const { return 3; }
};

/**
 * Foo needs to contain the following functions:
 * 
 * - int Foo::foo()
 */
template <typename Foo>
void doSomething(const Foo& foo) {
    std::cout << foo.foo() << "\n";
    std::cout << foo.bar() << "\n"; // I want this to be an error!
}

int main() {
    FooImpl foo;
    doSomething(foo); // No error if this is commented out
    return 0;
}
```

Sure, the doc comment can rot, but so can the concept. Is there a way to produce a compile error if you use a function on a concept that is not contained in the concept?

Comment: No, there's no good way. Concepts are mostly just a fancy replacement for `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat + possibility to "overload" on requirements.

Comment: @Evg `std::enable_if` lets you do that too. The only truly new thing is concept subsumption, where a more constratined overload automatically gets precedence the more relaxed ones.

Comment: *"Another two weeks later: Write a test"* -- This looks to me like the biggest issue in your scenario, not the behavior of concepts. The test was written four weeks later than it should have. (If it was written when it should have been, it would have caught the modification.)

Comment: You might write a test immediately but include a `Foo` that has a `bar`. The problem with the lack of definition checking is not something that can be easily fixed with tests.

Answer (score 0):

No.

What you want is true generics or "definition checking" as it was called in the C++ proposals. It was included in the C++0x (pre-C++11) concepts, but those were never accepted by the committee.

There are legitimately some C++ factors that make writing concepts more difficult if they were definition checked. For example, the concept in the post allows:

```
foo.foo() // #1
```

but not necessarily calling on a `const` or rvalue:

```
Foo(foo).foo() // there are types for which #1 works but this does not
static_cast<const Foo>(foo).foo() // same
```

That the result is convertible to an `int` means that you can use it where an `int` can, except you can't: if `foo()` directly returns an `int`, it can be implicitly converted to a type that is implicitly convertible from `int`. However, if `foo()` returns something convertible to `int`, it cannot be implicitly converted to this other type.

```
use(foo.foo()) // where use(const Bar&) and Bar is implicitly convertible from int
               // works if foo() returns int, but not convertible to int
```

So... as much as I and others would have preferred a "definition checked" version, to write a concept in such a C++ could be even trickier.

So... no, there is not a way to provide that compile error.

Concepts may have other advantages. For example, overloads will be ranked according to "subsumption": an overload taking a more specific concept will be chosen in place of one taking a more generic concept.